# Setting a ref in a callback doesn't save the actual element (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, canvas, refs

I think I'm misunderstanding how refs are supposed to work. 
In a component, I'm returning:

`return <canvas ... ref={(ref) => this._canvas = ref}/>`

Later, in `componentDidMount`, I attempt to access the ref as:

`this._canvas.getContext('2d')`

which errors out because `this._canvas` refers to some kind of constructor as shown below:

[image]
My questions are:

1. What is the best way to save a reference to the actual canvas element so I can do things like `getContext` later on, and
2. What exactly is that constructor function, and what is its purpose?

I noticed that calling `this._canvas.getDOMNode()` returns the actual element, which seems to be what I'm looking for. However, I'd rather not go through and replace all references to `this._canvas` without fully understanding what I'm doing.

Comment: Which version of React are you using?

Comment: 0.13.3. Yeah, I know...

Comment: Possibly might be worth it to update to 0.14, because of [this change](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html#dom-node-refs).

Comment: Ah! Great find, thank you.